# Deleting duplicates of tables

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, delete-row

In my `activity_logs`, it contains columns: `material_name`, `user_id`, `mod_result` (this marks a test if Pass/Fail), `cert_links`. Somehow the users generate twice the entry of the `material_name` with the `cert_links` column left blank.

I can list duplicates to all `user_id` with:

```
SELECT user_id, material_name, mod_score, cert_links, start_time 
FROM activity_logs 
WHERE mod_result = 'Pass' AND cert_links = ''
```

I want to delete the duplicate entries that has `mod_result = 'Fail'` and `cert_links = ''`

Comment: two queries are the same?? what do you mean by the **duplicate**? could you please show some outputs?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.. i don't know how to post outputs yet. But the idea is to collect all the same material_name with mod_result = 'Fail' and cert_links = '' from all users

Comment: Is the whole row same that is user_id, material_name etc??

Comment: they have the same row except for the time.

Comment: `mod_score` and `mod_result` are different fields?

Comment: they are different fields mod_result = 'Pass' mod_score=100

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
Delete from activity_logs WHERE mod_result = 'Fail' AND cert_links = '' or ''NULL'
```

Comment: Tried it, but I want to keep 1 row from the duplicates.

Comment: your `WHERE mod_result = 'Fail' AND cert_links = '' or ''NULL'` is not a valid MySQL syntax;

Comment: I would like to keep the newest record.

Answer (score 0):

3 steps:

Step 1: Move the non duplicates (unique tuples) into a temporary table

CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1 GROUP BY [COLUMN TO remove duplicates BY];

Step 2: delete the old table

DROP TABLE old_table;

Step 3: rename the new_table to the name of the old_table

RENAME TABLE new_table TO old_table;

Comment: Thanks but I don't wish to delete the duplicate records of the entire table; what I want is to remove duplicate titles (material_name) with reference to its user_id.

So if John Doe has 2 ABC Materials recorded I want to delete the rest and leave only one entry.

Comment: How can I group them per user_id and list down all material_names then  keep one record/delete duplicates for every material?